# Big data memory issue in R

Tags: r, performance, machine-learning, sparse-matrix, large-data

I've created a tdm matrix in R which I want to write to a file. This is a large sparse matrix in simple triplet form, ~ 20,000 x 10,000. When I convert it to a dense matrix to add columns by cbind, I get low memory errors and the process does not complete. I don't want to increase my RAM.

Also, I want to - 
- bind the tf and tfidf matrices together 
- save the sparse/dense matrix to csv
- run batch machine learning algorithms such as J48 implementation of weka.

How do I save/ load dataset and run the batch ML algorithms within memory constraints?

If I can write a sparse matrix to a data store, can I run ml algorithms in R on a sparse matrix, and within memory constraints?

Comment: see `glmnet` package in `R` - it accepts sparse matricies could be a more efficient for your situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be several solutions:

1) Convert your matrix from double to integer, if you are dealing with integer numbers. Integers needs less memory comparing to double numbers.

2) Try the [bigmemory](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/) package.

Comment: The [ff package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/index.html) and [colbycol](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/colbycol/index.html) could be useful too.

Comment: Thanks everyone
@djhurio - I have called 'TermDocumentMatrix()' which creates a simple triplet matrix in integer. I need to cbind to add columns, due to which I have to convert it to a matrix or data.frame.

I also need to run other algos besides glm, such as J48 on sparse matrices.

1. Is it possible to cbind as simple triplet matrix?
2. Since I cannot run algos besides those in glmnet on sparse matrices, and I cannot create a sparse arff to run directly in Weka, can I run other ML algos if my data is non-contiguously/file-backed allocated through packages such as bigmemory/ff?

Comment: Also, is it easier to manage memory in Python using Scikit-learn. Thanks

Comment: @sudeepo, it is hard to give a precise answer without having the data. You have to try solutions mentioned here and see what works and what does not work. You can come back with more specific questions after you have tried to tackle the problem.

Comment: Hi, I had to use the ff package and Amazon EC2 with larger RAM too. Thanks for the answer, and sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

A third solution, in addition to those mentioned by @djhurio, is to use cloud computing services, such as those provided by [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/). You don't mention how much RAM do you require exactly, but from I could quickly gather from the current price list, using these services will gain you up to 244 Gb of RAM. I doubt you'll need that much in reality, and if all you need is 16-32 Gb, the price will not be prohibitive at all.

If you are an academic user, you may want to look into `RevoScaleR` in Revolution R, a commercial version of R which is available for free in the academic context. This software handles large objects out of the box.